# Get the values from array by using the name of key

Tags: arrays

I have coding mentioned below. I want to get the values of response_text and response_code from this array. Anyone can help me how to get the particular key values.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_OPS_version] => 0.9
    [protocol] => XCP
    [request_response_time] => 0.441
    [response_text] => Command completed successfully
    [is_search_completed] => 1
    [action] => REPLY
    [attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [suggestion] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 0
                    [response_text] => Missing tld list, supported tlds are [.com,.net,.org,.info,.biz,.us,.mobi]
                    [response_code] => 500
                    [is_success] => 0
                )

        )

    [response_code] => 200
    [is_success] => 1
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the namespace System.Reflection, try using PropertyInfo[] info = stdClass.GetProperies(), then just loop through each property and check the value on a debug mode.

Comment: Can u please explain with an example how to use namespace for that one

Comment: PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;
// Get the properties of 'Type' class object.
myPropertyInfo = <stdClassObject>.GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myPropertyInfo[i].ToString());
}

Answer (score 0):

In php also, we can fetch the value as mentioned below

$check=$results->{'attributes'}->suggestion->response_text;

Reference   :   http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/161452-stdclass-object-get_object_vars